# How to create columns for text file in Python based on an array

Tags: python, arrays, fwrite

I have an array and I would like to save this array as column based to a txt file. For example, after every 3 iterations I would like to go to a new column. I saw some similar problems which is solved by using zip function, however, it doesn't help since I would have more than 100 arrays if I use the zip function.

```
 a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
```

Output context is like:

```
1 4 7 10
2 5 8 11
3 6 9 12
```

Comment: @Sayse fwrtie could be f.write as in file.write for writing to a text file

Comment: @Sayse OP also want s to save the value in a text file.

Comment: Have you tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can solve this without `zip` like this:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
rows = 3
for i in range(rows):
    row = a[i::rows]
    print(*row)
```

You can replace `print(*row)` with `file.write(' '.join(str(x) for x in row)+'\n')` to write to a file.